# Monitor upload/download progress via `CloudBlockBlob` class?

Tags: events, azure-blob-storage

If you're transferring a `Stream` to Azure Blob Storage via the official [`CloudBlockBlob`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudblockblob.aspx) class, how does one monitor the progress of the upload/download itself? I was expecting some events to that class since it's a network IO class but none seem to exist.

Right now our application sends the entire stream to `CloudBlockBlob` and it appears like it's done - but we know `CloudBlockBlob` is still uploading the bytes delivered to it in the stream, so it's really not done...

Am I missing something? Is an entirely different way of doing this (without reinventing the wheel!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the code at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/03/06/asynchronous-parallel-block-blob-transfers-with-progress-change-notification-2-0.aspx.  It uses a ProgressStream wrapper around the file stream in order to raise events whenever data is transferred.